# Pepperを自律移動させる場合に外部(ラズベリーパイ等)からのデータを取得して制御する方法を知りたい

Tags: android-studio, raspberry-pi

こんにちは。Pepperを使って地域施設の館内説明を自動化しようとしています。
開発担当を今年引き継いだのですがこれまではChoregrapheで開発していた環境が
今年からはAndroid Studioに変更になってしまったので一からは作り直しています。

Android Studioの基本は大体理解したのですがローカライズという機能は外部の影響で途中で停止してしまうという事でその他の手法を試そうという事になりました。
そこでChoregraphe時の記事でラズベリーパイとpepperを通信してデータに応じてpepperが発話するというものがありました。

参考:
[今回は温度センサとPepperを連動させたラズパイハンズオン！](https://pepper-atelier-akihabara.jp/archives/2213)

このような事は現在のAndroid Studioでも可能でしょうか？
理想の形としてはpepperとラズベリーパイを通信して、ラズベリーパイにライントレースを搭載してラズベリーパイのデータをもとにpepperが自律移動して一定の場所で停止し館内説明を行うというものです。

そして可能ならどのようにラズベリーパイと通信を行うのか、その他の情報に関しては全くの無知ですので分かりやすく教えていただけたらと思います。

Comment: Android Studio は単に IDE です。Pepper SDK for Android Studio を使おうとなさってるということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、Pepper SDK for Android Studioを使おうとしています。